# apache poi - any way to convert a list of Pojo to HSSFSheet?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Would be a pretty awesome feature in apache POI `HSSFBeanHelper.toHssfSheet(HSSFWorkbook workbook, List<Object> obj)` that would create a HSSFSheet from a list of Pojo.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two API's that both sit on top of POI that provide kind-of the functionality you suggest:

- http://jxls.sourceforge.net/
- http://jett.sourceforge.net/

Both libraries are extremely similar, on the JETT website there's even a handy [comparison table](http://jett.sourceforge.net/jxls_comp.html)

Both take an Excel file as a template and will fill it up with variables you provide (and these variables can include one or more lists of objects).  So, creating a spreadsheet from a list of POJO's is very simple, but it's equally easy to provide Excel formulas that will be executed using the filled in data, and even charts and for me that's the real power of these libraries.

Comment: Pretty strong answer. I'm trying the top guy out now, seems to be exactly what i was lookin for.

Comment: Glad you like it.  I'm a long-time user of jXLS but I must say several features of Jett make it very tempting to give that one a spin as well - complicated templates with lots of loops is where I suspect Jett will really shine.